# Regex not working on html input pattern

Tags: html, regex

I constructed a regex to match datetimes in the format *dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii*.
This works great on regex tester: https://regex101.com/r/AX4nxj/1
But when used in the pattern attribute of an input field it does not validate at all. You can even type just "a" and it will submit.

```
<input type="text" required="required" pattern="(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))\.(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}\ (?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d" name="formName" />
```

You can try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/h2uwhL70/

Why is that? :( Does HTML use a different regex format or what?

Comment: The only error is the backslash before a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your regex is a little bit verborage and wrong :D. So try this:

```
 ^(0+[1-9]|[1-2]+[0-9]|3+[0-1]).(0+[1-9]|1+[0-2]).\d{4} (00|[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])$
```

Comment: maybe just flip the \d\d\d\d to \d{4} but I like it!

Comment: thank you. i don't know much about regex but that does not look right and also does not work (on both regex tester and html pattern).

Comment: I mean for example why are there three ":"? what is this supposed to match

Comment: sniperd, indeed \d{4} is a way more better, thanks for the help. @grindit, the three ":" is my mistake, I didn't realize that you wanna "." instead of ":". Now I edited the answer. Try it again.

Comment: but the regex you suggested does also allow d.m.yyyy h:i (single digit).
I managed to correct it by myself with my noobie knowledge. also changed yyyy to yy.

`^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]){2}.(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]).\d{2} (00|[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]){2}:([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]){2}$`

just the month part does not work with {2}. can you help me with it?